# Complex Exponential False "Proof" That All Integers Are $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, fake-proofs

The following false "proof" is attributed to Thomas Clausen in 1827, and was stated on page 79 of Nahin's *An Imaginary Tale*.

$e^{i2\pi n}=1$ for all integers $n$. So

\begin{align*}
ee^{i2\pi n}=e&=e^{1+i2\pi n}\\
&=\left(e^{1+i2\pi n}\right)^{1+i2\pi n}\\
&=e^{(1+i2\pi n)^2}=e^{1+i4\pi n-4\pi^2n^2}\\
&=e^{1+i4\pi n}e^{-4\pi^2n^2}
\end{align*}
But $e^{1+i4\pi n}=e$, therefore $e^{-4\pi^2n^2}=1$. But that last equation is only true for $n=0$. We started with a statement true for all integers $n$, and through a series of (apparently) valid steps ended with a statement true only for $0$. Therefore all integers are $0$. Where is the mistake?

Comment: The identity $(e^a)^b=e^{ab}$ does not hold in general for complex numbers. Not that this _explains_ anything, but that is the error in the proof.

Comment: Indeed, it does not hold in general even for rational numbers. Consider the nonsense expression $-1 = (-1)^{1} = ((-1)^{2})^{1/2} = (1)^{1/2} = 1$

Comment: Now that we have an answer in a comment, tell us: What did Clausen say about it?

Comment: As far as I know, Clausen himself never offered a resolution, and Nahin doesn't either. You can find a (German) publication of his work containing this in the following citation: Thomas Clausen, Aufgabe 53, J. Reine Angew. Math. 2 (1827), 286–287.

Comment: Nahin does offer a solution in the Appendix D, at least in my 2016 paperback edition.

Answer (score 1):

See [Failure of power and logarithm identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities) and [Complex exponents with positive real bases 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_positive_real_bases_2) which explains this exact problem. Also consider the related problem of $e^{-4\pi^2n^2}=\left(e^{i2\pi n}\right)^{i2\pi n}=1^{i2\pi n}=1$, which forgets that, in this scheme, the power of 1 is involves a multivalued log of 1 in an exponent.